# Quick Javascript form query

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have coded a very simple javascript form, however I cant get it to run properly. As you will see in the below code & fiddle. I need the form to validate all the sections and ensure that only alphanumerical information is added in first name and the last name boxes. Also I would like to form to return an error when nothing is entered in 1 or all of the fields.

I'm new to Javascript coding so please can someone assist me with this query. I'm sure there will be a quick and easy fix.

Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/cal122/juwt6wvv/6/

```js
function ValidationEvent() {

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("name2").value;
    var contact = document.getElementById("message").value;

    if (name != '' && name2 != '' && message != '') {
        if (/^([\w-\.]+ $/.test(name)) {
            alert("All type of validation has done on OnSubmit event.");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Please provide valid first name!");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please provide valid second name!");
        return false;
    }
    } else {
        alert("Please put some text in the message box");
        return false;
    }
    } else {
        alert("All fields are required.....!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.main {
 width:333px;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-right:-28px;
 border:1px solid black;
 float:right;
 z-index:-1;
}
input[type=text] {
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 padding:5px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 margin-top:5px;
 border:2px solid #ccc;
 color:#4f4f4f;
 font-size:16px;
}

label {
 color:black;
 font-size:14px;
}
input[type=submit] {
 font-size:18px;
 background: #CF1559;
 cursor:pointer;
 width:40%;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
 background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidationEvent()">
<label>First Name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Enter your last name" type="text">
<label>Message:</label>
<input id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: [Regular Expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @BjørnSørensen the form is not validating and I am unable to understand why?

Comment: For  a start, check the regex code line  and rewrite that part.

Comment: @sam Thanks Sam, sorry I cant see what I have done in this line. Can you assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is that you are not using your regular expression correctly.

This line:

```
if (name == /^([\w-\.]+ $) {
```

Should look something like this:

```
if (/^([\w-\.]+)$/.test(name)) {
```

Note that the regular expression is wrapped in slashes (`/ /`). We also utilize the `test` function to determine if the value of `name` is found by the `RegExp` object.

I would recommend reading up on regular expression on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Additionally, there are a number of online RegExp testing tools to help you try your patterns. I like to use RegExp 101: https://regex101.com/

The secondary issue is that the if / else logic is very broken:

```
if (name != '' && name2 != '' && message != '') {
    if (/^([\w-\.]+ $/.test(name)) {
        alert("All type of validation has done on OnSubmit event.");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please provide valid first name!");
        return false;
    }
} else {
    alert("Please provide valid second name!");
    return false;
}
} else {
    alert("Please put some text in the message box");
    return false;
}
} else {
    alert("All fields are required.....!");
    return false;
}
```

You do not have `if` statements that match up with your `else` statements for the other cases you are trying to trap for:

```
if (name != '' && name2 != '' && message != '') {
    if (/^([\w-\.]+)$/.test(name)) {
        alert("All type of validation has done on OnSubmit event.");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please provide valid first name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (/^([\w-\.]+)$/.test(name2)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please provide valid second name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (/^([\w-\.]+)$/.test(message)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Please put some text in the message box");
        return false;
    }
} else {
    alert("All fields are required.....!");
    return false;
}
```

Here, there is an `if` for every `else`. Beyond this, the validation may not work if you have incorrect regular expression. I cannot correct that here, but you should be able to utilize the links above to fix that yourself. Bear in mind that you should **never** rely on client side validation and should always double-check your validation on the server side before it goes to a database or API.

Comment: Thanks Justin I will be sure to read up on this some more. I have updated the fiddle. However validation still doesn't appear to be working?

Comment: The regex shown: `/^([\w-\.]+ $/` is not valid. it is missing the closing capture group right-paren.

Comment: @cal I have updated my answer to include other issues you have with your code.

Comment: @justin pearce thanks for this Justin. The validation isn't functional yet however your explanation was great really appreciate your time.